# Linux trouble with insserv

Tags: linux

So after my latest update I get this error message

[image]

```
insserv: Script ntp has overlapping Default-Start and Default-Stop runlevels (2 3 4 5) and (2 3 4 5). This should be fixed.
insserv: Script ssh has overlapping Default-Start and Default-Stop runlevels (2 3 4 5) and (2 3 4 5). This should be fixed.
insserv: Script sysstat has overlapping Default-Start and Default-Stop runlevels (2 3 4 5) and (2 3 4 5). This should be fixed.
```

I tried `insserv -d /etc/init.d/ntp` :

```
insserv -dv /etc/init.d/ntp
insserv: FATAL: service mountkernfs has to exist for service udev
insserv: FATAL: service checkroot has to exist for service cryptdisks
insserv: FATAL: service urandom has to exist for service networking
insserv: FATAL: service mountdevsubfs has to exist for service hwclock
insserv: FATAL: service bootmisc has to exist for service live-tools
insserv: exiting now!
```

But mountkernfs, checkroot, mountdevsubfs and bootmisc are not in my system

There is my `/etc/init.d/ntp` header which is the same for ssh and sysstat

[image]

```
cat /etc/init.d/ntp
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        ntp
# Required-Start:  $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:   $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 
# Short-Description: Start NTP daemon
### END INIT INFO

I tried `inssertv -d /etc/init.d/ntp` but I get 
[enter image description here][3]
insserv -dv /etc/init.d/ntp
insserv: FATAL: service mountkernfs has to exist for service udev
insserv: FATAL: service checkroot has to exist for service cryptdisks
insserv: FATAL: service urandom has to exist for service networking
insserv: FATAL: service mountdevsubfs has to exist for service hwclock
insserv: FATAL: service bootmisc has to exist for service live-tools
insserv: exiting now!
```

I running :

```
DISTRIB_ID=Parrot
DISTRIB_RELEASE=4.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Parrot 4.10"
PRETTY_NAME="Parrot GNU/Linux 4.10"
NAME="Parrot GNU/Linux"
ID=parrot
ID_LIKE=debian
VERSION="4.10"
VERSION_ID="4.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.parrotsec.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://community.parrotsec.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://community.parrotsec.org/"
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @vile-celma It is difficult to know when and how to use StackOverflow. Use this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for asking good questions.

Answer (score 2):

change init file in `etc/init.d/ntp` with their default start and stop.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rpcbind portmap
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
```

thats work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So the I edited `etc/init.d/ntp`,`etc/init.d/ssh` and `etc/init.d/sysstat` whit `Default Stop : 0 1 6` and now the output of insserv look like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsVMR.png)

Edit :
so now i have installed initscripts with `sudo apt-get install initscripts`
And the previous error messages no longer appear but I get another one :
`insserv  insserv: FATAL: service rpcbind is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service nfs-kernel-server insserv: exiting now!`

I dont know how to set the runlevel for rpcbind . Do I have to set Default Start and Stop for this one because for me its look fine :
`cat /etc/init.d/rpcbind`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# start/stop rpcbind daemon.

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rpcbind portmap
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: RPC portmapper replacement
```